# How to render DateTime in format DD/MM/YYYYTHH:mm ASP.NET CORE 5.0 MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, datatable, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to render `DateTime` in format  `DD/MM/YYYYTHH:mm` in `C# ASP.NET CORE 5.0 MVC` but I am not sure is it good idea to render in backend side or in frontend. Since in frontend side I use `DataTable`
Currently this is format which I get in my `datatable`

```
2021-03-05T13:22:48.3190414
```

But I want to be formated as

```
05-03-2021T13:22
```

I try couple of solution something like in datatable

```
{
                "data": "dateAndTime", "width": "15%",
                "def": function () { return new Date(); },
                "displayFormat": 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                "wireFormat": 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                "keyInput": false
            },

 [Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme slanja")]
        public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

Also in backend I try something like this:

```
ticketVM.Ticket.DateAndTime = DateTime.Parse("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

And get this kind of error

```
The string 'DD/MM/YYYY' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index '0'.
```

Any advice and suggestion how to get format render in format DD/MM/YYYYTHH:mm ??

Comment: `String '13/12/2021' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: You need to _parse_ the format that the _string_ actually _has_. If you want to lose the millis: set them to 0. If you then want to _display_ another format, you need to format the datetime value accordingly. DateTime itself _has no format_ - it's just a number.

Comment: How to format DateTIme in format DD/MM/YYYYTHH:mm. You mean format in Model by using 
` [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm}")]`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gK6fTz , Your format is incorrect. See [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). It needs to be `"dd/MM/yyyyTHH:mm"`.

Comment: ^^ Example with parsing: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cdenxp

Comment: <input asp-for="Ticket.DateAndTime" disabled class="form-control" />
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Format String means it's a string after format:

```
public string DateAndTime()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
}
```

You can replace :

```
[Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme slanja")]
public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
```

to

```
[Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme slanja")]
public string DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```

About the ToString rules you can see  [Fildor](/users/982149/fildor)'s commets :
See [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) .

Comment: Where to include this ? In Model or ... ?

Comment: You can replace :

[Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme slanja")]
public DateTime DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

to 

[Display(Name = "Datum i vrijeme slanja")]
public string DateAndTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

About the tostring rules you can see  [Fildor](/users/982149/fildor)'s commets :
See [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) .

Comment: Not sure how it is good idea to store day as `String` but however thank you for suggestion and you answer